# Is there any proposal in the pipeline to allow any parameter in a template?

Tags: c++, c++20

The problem with templates is that you must specify a particular item you want as a parameter, such as a `typename`, a `template` or a `value`.  However, you can't say, specialize the template based on if the next parameter is any of those three.

I was thinking that if there will be a way to specialize based on these parameters like in the following example:

```
template <...Xs>
struct X;

template <template <typename...> class TT>
struct X<TT> {};

template <typename T>
struct X<T> {};

template <typename T, T I>
struct X<I> {};
```

This is a template that takes a parameter pack of unspecified parameters, and is can only be accessed though specialization.

This allows the ability to have more control over template specialization and accept any parameter list.  Does anyone know if there is anything being discussed about a feature like this?

If not, what's the proposal process?

Comment: That's basically template overloading. And I wish that we have something like this in the future.

Comment: @geza No. That is still template specialization. I was attempting to specify a template with a parameter pack of uunspecified parameters.

Comment: Maybe, whatever we call this feature :) it's like function overloading. It would be useful, if a template could be instantiated with a callable (so it is a type), or with a function pointer (so it is a value).

Answer (score 1):

[Universal Template Parameters](https://wg21.link/p1985) was submitted for the Prague meeting in Feb 2020. It introduces `template auto X` as the syntax for an arbitrary template entity. It was discussed in EWG-I and received feedback. I believe the authors will bring it back for the next meeting in Varna.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would appear that there isn't an official proposal out there as yet, but there is a suggestion as to how it could be done [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/sZZ-Weg-kUA).  It is attempting to reuse the keyword `template` in a naked context to define a template parameter that will take a unspecified template parameter type (UTPT).

I had written another proposal before I knew about that one [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-proposals/TrvJIkdAr7U/usYX-xCoAwAJ).  It uses no keyword to indicate that the template parameter type (TPT) is unspecified. 
 It shows a side by side comparison that shows a real world example of a template which would benefit from having a UTPT and how it will look with the suggestion implemented.

I hope you might find these interesting and if so, please comment on either one of them, so that they can get more attention.